# exec function not working properly in python 3.6

Tags: python, function, python-3.6, python-exec

Code I wrote

```
tile1=0; player1=1; turn=player1

def s():
   global tile1,turn,player1
   print("Before",tile1)
   string='tile' + '1' # I am getting 1 by some function that's why I need to create variable string                                     
   exec("%s=%d" %(string,turn))
   print("After",tile1)  
s()
```

**Output what I expected**
Before 0
After 1

**Output what i got**
Before 0
After 0

If I write the code without the function , it gives the expected output

```
tile1=0; player1=1; turn=player1
print("Before",tile1)
string='tile' + '1'                                  
exec("%s=%d" %(string,turn))
print("After",tile1)
```

I want to ask how to correct this code so that I get the expected output. Also, I am not allowed to use list and dictionary.

Comment: you have to print "string" as that is now "title1"

Comment: Can you explain with code as I am not understanding your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to specify the scope when you use `exec` inside a function.

If you change it to:

```
exec("%s=%d" %(string,turn), None, globals())
```

It works as expected because you have no `local` variables (you declared them `global`) so you pass in the global scope as `local` scope to `exec` so it knows about `tile1` and `turn`.

---

However, it's misusing `exec`, you shouldn't use it that way!